# Xamarin iOS: Making UICollectionView Cells Dynamic

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I am using UICollectionView for my Xamarin iOS project.

Say, I display 7 CollectionViewCell and each CollectionViewCell has Image and Button. If the button is clicked I want to delete the image and want the rest of the cells to move one up.
Example: If I have 7 cells and I clicked on the button on 5th cell, I want to delete the image on 5th cell and it should display image that was previously displayed on 6th cell, and 6th cell should display image that was previously displayed on 7th cell.

When I delete the image and use 'collectionview.ReloadData()' it doesnt work. I can see that the images are deleted in the background but not being updated onto the collectionview.

Can anyone please advise?

**UPDATE**

Each Cell has Image and a button. On button Click I want to remove the image and want the rest of the cells to move one up.

**Cell**

```
private void DeleteImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //imageNum is the cellIndex num
        newViewModel.DeletePhotoCommand.Execute(imageNum);
        var path1 = collectionView.GetIndexPathsForSelectedItems();
        collectionView.ReloadItems(path1);
        }
```

**ViewModel**

```
        private readonly ICommand deletePhotoCommand;

        public ICommand DeletePhotoCommand { get { return deletePhotoCommand; } }

        public NewViewModel()
                {
                    deletePhotoCommand = new BaseMvxCommand<int>(DeletePhoto);
                }
public string Photo1{get; set; }
public string Photo2{get; set; }
public string Photo3{get; set; }
public string Photo4{get; set; }
public string Photo5{get; set; }

    public void DeletePhoto(int imageNum)
            {
                imageNum++;
                switch (imageNum)
                {
                    case 1:
                        if (Photo1 != null)
                        {
                            Photo1 = Photo2;
                            Photo2 = Photo3;
                            Photo3 = Photo4;
                            Photo4 = Photo5;
                            Photo5 = null;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (Photo2 != null)
                        {
                            Photo2 = Photo3;
                            Photo3 = Photo4;
                            Photo4 = Photo5;
                            Photo5 = null;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (Photo3 != null)
                        {
                            Photo3 = Photo4;
                            Photo4 = Photo5;
                            Photo5 = null;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if (Photo4 != null)
                        {
                            Photo4 = Photo5;
                            Photo5 = null;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Photo5 = null;
                        break;
                }
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Photo1);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Photo2);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Photo3);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Photo4);
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Photo5);
            }
```

Comment: Don't you want to simply remove the row that was clicked?

Comment: How can I do that? Also, I am using MVVM so the images info are in ViewModels, they binded to the view.

Comment: It's for sure that that's possible to do like what you want, but you should put some code, or we can not find where the issue is because the description sounds no problem.

Comment: @AlancLiu I updated the question and added my code.

Comment: @NRitH Updated my question

Comment: This is very different than what you sent me in the support case. Hopefully the working solution I gave you there will help you in your real project as well.

Comment: @jgoldberger It did. Thank you.